# How do I modify the pxe config in MAAS?

Tags: maas

I'm using MAAS, during the commissioning step, I have full error on the screen

```
timeout: killing /sbin/modprobe -bv pci
```

I investigated a little and apparently it's an acpi issue.
So I tried to change and add a parameter to this file /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default.

I added those options in the default

```
APPEND noacpi noapm pci=noacpi lba acpi=off apm=off
```

But each time I restart the maas-pserv run the commissioning procedure this file is re-regenerated.

How to overcome this?

Thanks!

EDIT1: I saw that in the cobbler logs

```
Thu May  3 15:27:56 2012 - INFO | generating GPXE/PXE configuration files
Thu May  3 15:27:56 2012 - WARNING | warning: kernel option length exceeds 255
Thu May  3 15:27:56 2012 - INFO | generating: /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/01-00-1d-09-f0-4b-c2
```

But generating configuration from which default file? 
There is so many files in /etc/cobbler/pxe

Answer (score 5):

You can't technically modify the PXE config file in/from MAAS. You have to manually edit it. Every time you add node to MAAS, a PXE config file will be created for one of the MAC Address of the node. In your case, and based on your logs, you would have to edit the following file:

```
/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/01-00-1d-09-f0-4b-c2
```

And add

`noacpi noapm pci=noacpi lba acpi=off apm=off`

to the `append` line. It should look something like::

```
append initrd=/images/precise-i386/initrd.gz  locale=  locale=en_US priority=critical text  auto url=http://192.168.122.1/cblr/svc/op/ks/system/node-1577c5ae-957c-11e1-9a87-58946bf1d72c hostname=node-01001s09f04bc2 domain=local suite=precise noacpi noapm pci=noacpi lba acpi=off apm=off
```

Hope this helps!